# Scheme program to turn every element of a list into atoms

Tags: scheme

I need a program that takes a list as input and turns every element found in the list into atoms. Here's what i have so far but i keep running into errors.

```
    (define make-lat
      (lambda (l)
(cond
  ((null? l) (quote ()))
  (else
   (cond
     ((list? (car l))
      (cons (caar l)
            make-lat (cdr l)))
      (else 
       ((atom? (car l))
        (cons (car l)
       (make-lat(cdr l)
           )))))))))
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Sample input and output please.

Comment: Firstly: `make-lat (cdr l)` is VERY wrong.

Comment: If you do a search for "flatten" you should find some stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks a little disorganized to me, and I think you might want to think about following the steps in the [How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org) Design Recipe:

Step one: can you write a purpose statement for your program? It should say what the function does.

Step two: can you write a contract? It should say what kind of data the program takes in, and 
what it produces. You've got to be specific, here, and any kind of data that you specify must either be built-in or have an explicit "data definition".

Step three: write some test cases! Provide a sample input, and the output that you expect.

For more design recipe goodness, check out [How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/).

Comment: Why are otherwise excellent HtDP design recipe answers so often expressed condescendingly?  This tone, along with the irrational hand-holding language limitations the book imposes, really turns me off of a good resource with a lot of good advice.

Comment: I apologize. Reading over my answer again, I can see that it reads in a very condescending way. In my defense, I was trying to poke fun at myself--it's easy to feel like a broken record, when all you say to students is "follow the design recipe. follow the design recipe. follow the design recipe.

Comment: Second comment: I've edited my original response. Your comment was well-taken. Well, part of it, anyhow. Your comment about the "irrational hand-holding limitations," though, doesn't wash. The real question is this: have you thought about the class of errors that's eliminated by the limitations you describe?

Comment: I saw your comment and went back to look again at the HtDP languages.  I thought that the Beginning Student language lacked `list`, for example, but I was wrong; it's a convention of the book.

Why should students be made to write `(cons 3 (cons 'dollars (cons 'and (cons 53 (cons 'cents empty)))))` instead of `(list 3 'dollars 'and 53 'cents)`?  That's pure handholding, and it discourages strong students by treating them like they can't learn how lists work.

Maybe the problem is that I disagree with the premise of the otherwise good book: I don't think everyone can or should learn to program.

Comment: The `list` function is unhelpful, and often actively harmful, when teaching students how to write recursive functions. We want them to understand recursive data in general---not just lists! Teaching a one-off abbreviation that obscures structure too early works against that. There are too many programmers that can handle lists and arrays but fall to pieces when they have to deal with trees; we want to avoid producing more of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your question looks like homework.

Here's a couple of things you could do to try and debug.

- Use the Repl to try out parts of the function. E.g if in a cond, you are checking for null, you could do it on the REPL too.

`(null? '(1 2 3))` or `(null? '())`

- Check individual S-Exps. Are you sure that every function that you call has an opening and closing parens.
- As a tip, simplify your cond's. You don't need to nest conds. You can put all conditions one by one.